# Unable to send data from Logstash on machine1 to MongoDB running on machine2

Tags: mongodb, logstash

I am trying to send data from logstash, (running on macine1) to MongoDB, (running on machine2), using the mongo output plugin for logstash.
I installed the mongo plugin using, the command, bin/logstash-plugin install file:///c:/path/to/logstash-offline-plugins-7.13.4.zip.

My configuration for the output plugin is:
[Logstash config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxD5y.png)

output {

```
mongodb {
database => "mylogs"
collection => "prototype"
uri => "mongodb://<ipaddress>:27017/mylogs"
isodate => true
}
```

}

I get the message "Failed to send event to MongoDB, retrying in 3 seconds, MongoError: No server available matching preference" from logstash. For detailed error message check [Logstash message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fble7.png)

Kindly help me solve this issue

Comment: have you checked if machine1 can talk to machine2 and that the required ports are open?

Comment: @baudsp I ran the test-netconnection on 2 ports, one for mongoDB (port 27017) and the other, the listening port for logstash (port 1010) from my system to machine2 (the one where logstash and mongoDB is running). The connection failed in both the cases. But logstash is able to get input from my machine when run on machine2 and forward it to mongoDB on the same machine.

Comment: the command used was, test-netconnection -ComputerName <IPADDRESS> -Port <PORT>,